# How do you make two user types, one of which has to pay in order register?

Tags: wordpress

Say I have a site with two types of user

```
contentCreator
```

and

```
contentUser
```

What I want to do is :

contentCreator has to pay to have an account, and once logged in, has feature set X.

contentUser can register for free, and once logged in, has feature set Y.

All I need is a pointer in the right direction to get me started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using a membership plugin where you have a free and a paid membership structure and limit the content access based on the user membership plan.

You can use plugins like [Simple Membership](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-membership/) and configure it to have both paid and free memberships.

Comment: This was all I needed. Marked as answer, thank you.